# Eclipse Indigo update error

Tags: android, eclipse, installation, text-editor

Dear friends I would like to kindly ask you for help with a broken Eclipse Indigo 3.8.
I have made Eclipse Indigo upgrade from 3.7 to 3.8 and ADT 21 install through "`Help - Install new software item`".

Now the editor in Eclipse doesnt work after upgrade. I cant view content of any files.
When I try to open something only error message is shown:

```
Problem Occurred:

An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.getScrollbarsMode()I
```

Also I noticed, that items "Android SDK manager" and "Android Virtual Device Manager" in menu "Window" is missing after update.

Because I didn't find no sollution for a long time I made a second installation of Eclipse in the meantime. I have downloaded new Eclipse Indigo from [eclipse.org/downloads](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/indigo/sr2) link. Then I made new SDK installation and import projects from old Eclipse workspace to the new Eclipse  workspace (using File - Import - Existing Projects Into Workspace). Then I had to go "Project properties" - "Java Compiler" - "Enable project specific settings" + "Compiler compliance level 1.6" and it worked on new installation.
This is my sollution in the moment.

Please do you have any idea what does this error mean and a way to solve this problem? Does this mean I should upgrade any component or re-download any part of Eclipse ?

Comment: Accordint to this site: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Older_Versions_Of_Eclipse I don't understand, how you updated to 3.8.

Comment: Through the "Check for updates" and "Install new software". First the ADT 21 was installed and then Eclipse was updated.